# type casting and equal operator precedence in php

Tags: php, operator-precedence

Why do these 2 statements not output the same result?
The only reason I can imagine is [operator precedence](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) which appears to the same for `==` and `===`.

```php
$a = (bool) 4 == 4;
$b = (bool) 4 === 4;

var_dump($a); // bool(true)
var_dump($b); // bool(false)
```

Comment: A type cast has higher precedence than `==`. You're doing `true == 4`.

Comment: It has to do with type juggling. `==` makes a boolean out of the second 4 because the first 4 is made into a boolean. `===` doesn't do any juggling, it just compares.

Comment: @deceze that's clear.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Looks like that's the answer I was looking for. Please turn it into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, [operator precedence](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) is the same for `==` and `===`. Clearly the difference here is the operator itself.

First we have to acknowledge that type casting has a higher precedence than these two comparison operators. So, in reality, you're doing:

```
$a = (TRUE == 4);
$b = (TRUE === 4);
```

When you do a `==` you're simply trying to see if the values are equal. Only values of the same type can be compared. Since you start with a boolean, the number 4 will therefore also be turned into a boolean. This is called [type juggling](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php). We already know that `(bool)4` is `TRUE`. So `$a` must be `TRUE`.

However, when you do a `===` there is no type juggling, instead it will only return `TRUE` if the two operands have the same value *and* type. Since a boolean isn't the same type as an integer `$b` must be `FALSE`.